# add xmlns:mdssi to XMLObject

Tags: java, xml, openxml, xml-namespaces

i'm doing a java project about digital signature on microsoft office files (docx, xlsx, pptx).

i can create an object which will be added in the xml signature using:

```
XMLSignatureFactory xml_fac = XMLSignatureFactory.newInstance("DOM");

XMLObject xml_object = XMLSignatureFactory.newXMLObject(...
ArrayList<XMLObject> obj_list = new ArrayList<XMLObject>();
obj_list.add(xml_object);

XMLSignature xml_sig = xml_fac.newXMLSignature(...,...,obj_list,...
```

however, this xml signature generated by java doesn't 
contain `xmlns` for the type `XMLObject`

for microsoft office to recognise this xml object:

```
<Object>
  <SignatureProperties>
    <SignatureProperty Id="idSignatureTime" Target="#idPackageSignature">
      <mdssi:SignatureTime>
        <mdssi:Format>YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD</mdssi:Format>
        <mdssi:Value>2011-04-02T10:10:10Z</mdssi:Value>
      </mdssi:SignatureTime>
    </SignatureProperty>
  </SignatureProperties>
</Object>
```

i have to add:

```
xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature"
```

into the opening `<Object>` tag

but `XMLObject` in java has no way to add this, it has only `Id`, `MimeType`, `Encoding`, and `Content`

any suggestions?

Comment: how to bring this question onto top of today's unanswered list?

Answer (score 0):

```
SignatureProperty property = XML_SIGNATURE_FACTORY.newSignatureProperty(
    ...);

SignatureProperties properties = XML_SIGNATURE_FACTORY.newSignatureProperties(
    Collections.singletonList(property), ...);

XMLObject object = XML_SIGNATURE_FACTORY.newXMLObject(
    Collections.singletonList(properties), ...);
```

---

Version 2:

Here comes story. I uses Java. (JSR-105)
I'm digging XML Digital Signature for W3C Widgets.

1. for Signature/Object
   -- It seems easy first time I saw the APIs. I just created `XMLObject` like above.
2. But, as spec says, I have to insert a `Reference` referring the `XMLObject` created by 1.
   -- What? How can I make a reference referring an output node?
   -- How can I return a Data for Nodes not even created yet?
3. I realized that I should prepare a `org.w3c.dom.Document` containing the `<Object>` element (and its children as purposed) and use it for the Reference.
   --> With your `URIDereferencer`, you can return a `NodeSetData` from this document's getDocumentElement() result.

---

So here comes the solution.

1. Make a `org.w3c.dom.Document` instance containing the `<Object>` element as its root element. You can add any attributes and child elements as you wish.
2. And you can generate an XML Signature as detached or `enveloping` scheme.

Check this out. This is where I found the solution. And I think your problem will be solved.
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/21/xml-signature-with-jsr-105.html#generate-an-enveloping-signature

Sorry for my poor English. I'm Korean. :)

My best regards.
Jin Kwon

Comment: finally somebody answered, however, the matter is not yet solved, what i need is adding the namespace "xmlns:mdssi=..." into the 'Object' opening tag like this: <Object xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature">